# Accessing form from scope inside resource error callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I'm doing client side validation on submit, if the form is valid, I call the resource, on success everything is fine, but now on error handler I do server side validation on my data transfer object bean as well which has some Hibernate validator annotations, when these fail, I return a json with failed field name and a message. Now I would like to set my input fields invalid from my Angular controller, but I am unable to access the form from scope and even as a parameter in my error callback function.

```
$scope.submit = function (saleForm) {
    if (saleForm.$invalid) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.sale.$save(function (sale) {
        $modalInstance.close(sale);
        $scope.alerts.push({type: 'success', msg: 'Sale successfully added!'});
    }, function (errors) {
        for (var field in errors.data) {
            $scope.saleForm.$setValidity(field, false); // <-- wrong approach?
        }
    })
};
```

The field names I get back from json match the ones on my web. What am I doing wrong here? With the loop I would like to set all the fields that were returned back to invalid state.

Comment: `$scope.saleForm[field].$setValidity(false);`

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hours' of undefined` with that. Input field in the form has the same name and id as the json response.

Comment: The scope on which the form is defined and the $scope object you are using are not the same.  In success and error callback use the same saleForm variable that you passed in submit. `saleForm.$setValidity(field,false);`

Comment: Ok so that seems to actually work what I tried before, which was `saleForm[field].$setValidity(false)`, but for that now when I change fields value on form then it stays with `ng-invalid` class. Does the $setValidity make the field permanently invalid for some reason, or how can I bypass that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the errors already mentioned in the comments above, you are also using the `$setValidity()` function incorrectly.

`$setValidity` accepts two arguments:
1. validationErrorKey (string)
2. isValid (boolean)

When you set the validity of validationErrorKey to `false`, the only way to "undo" it is to set the validity of the same validationErrorKey to `true`.
By calling `$setValidity(false)` you are essentially calling `$setValidity('false', undefined)` which is equivalent to `$setValidity('false', false)`.
But, since there is nothing that sets the validity to `true` for the validationErrorKey `'false'`, your controls stay invalid forever.

To solve this, you need to also specify the validationErrorKey.
E.g. an number-field can be invalid because it's not a number (validationErrorKey: `number`), because it exceeds the max allowed value (validationErrorKey: `max`), because it is required and empty (validationErrorKey: `required`) etc.

Thus, your server should also return the validationErrorKey (e.g. why it is not valid), so you can properly use:

```
saleForm[field].$setValidity(errorKey, false);
```